# Bootstrap Video Player HTML5

Tags: html, laravel-5

I'am use Bootstrap HTML5 class , but its allow for download the video. how i do to disable fiture download video?

screenshoot :
[image: Screnshoot video player]

this my code

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 autoplay">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{ asset("/tes.mp4") }}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that in two ways. 
1. You can set controlsList="nodownload" on the video tag to no show the download button

or You can use css to hide the the button. If you post the live video url then it would be easy to debug

Comment: using `controlList="nodownload"` is not working on me.

Comment: you need to apply this on a video tag

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help you Please put it in you Inframe tag.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{ asset("/tes.mp4") }}" controlsList="nodownload">
```

Usually It uses within `<video controls controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen">` tag, I think that would work as well!

Cheer you!